# Login with facebook app in ios app shows option in safari "Login with Facebook app" and its not working in ios 10.1

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-login, ios10

In my app, i am using login with a Facebook option. Where I set Facebook SDK behavior"FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative"

When I try to login with facebook its show me two option "Login with the facebook app" or "Login with phone or email" in ios 10.1. In ios 9 its direct shows me login page where email/password I have to enter

But in ios 10.1 it shows above two option and when I click on "Login with the Facebook app", it shows dialog "open in facebook" and on click of "open" button it authorizes to my app, Now it has to come back to my app but it stay in Safari view controller where two options are given of login and never come back to my app

[image]

Comment: The screen now shows on my iOS 9 device as well. The behaviour is the same that it stays in this view controller after navigating back from Facebook app, and no delegate method is called. Can someone please help us??

Comment: I found the reason why it's not working. It's because the url scheme returned when using "Log In With The Facebook App" option is different from the one returned from using "Log in with phone or email". One uses lower-cased suffix and the other is using upper-cased suffix which my program did not handle before. Fixing the suffix fixed the issue.

Comment: @user3216945 can you provide a answer with the description of what did you change, since I have the same issue

Comment: I had the same issue. When the dialog exits, it calls the "urlscheme" to launch your app again. It goes through the list url schemes as defined in the iOS app settings in the Facebook developer site. What happened for me was that I had the wrong url scheme defined there so it didn't know how to launch my app again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my application its happening because of salesforce sdk security option which cancel facebook login when app went to facebook app for authorization.
I disable snapshotview and facebook login works fine

```
[SalesforceSDKManager sharedManager].useSnapshotView = NO;
```

So this is not facebook issue but its happening due to third party sdk.

Comment: I am not using SalesForce and I have the same issue, so this issue has nothing to do with a third party sdk

Comment: Hey  Marco Pappalardo, In my application salesforce creating issue and i fixed it . I clearly mentioned that any third party sdk may causing this issue.

Comment: That is fine, however this issue exist also for other reasons and I don't think that accepting this answer will help the community, it would be interesting to find out what is the root cause in the Facebook SDK in order to make people having the same issue for different reason being able to use this question to solve that

Comment: Let me know if you find the root cause in the facebook sdk

Comment: Yea, I have a similar issue at the moment and I will update if I fix it :) thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 11, my in-app Facebook login was also going to the Facebook.com page instead of the device app. Based on the fix below, it seems that FB just changed the behavior default. Setting the button to system fixed it for me.

```
self.fbloginButton.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount;
```

That switched the app back to the fast app switching.

Answer (score 0):

```
     func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

     /*

      for facebook login

    */ 

            if #available(iOS 9.0 , *){
                return ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])

            }

      /*

       for google signin

     */
            return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url as URL?,
                                                     sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                                     annotation: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
        }
```